# Spouse in Skyrim keeps changing outfit when entering/leaving house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So in Skyrim I married Senna and bought Lakeview Manor, and used console commands to give my spouse more normal-looking clothes.  However, whenever she crosses the threshhold to the house (either to go wander around outside or to go back in), she will take off all the clothes I gave her and put her standard monk robes back on.  Removing the monk robes with the console makes her simply remove *all* her clothes whenever she goes through the door.  Either way, I can't get her to keep her new clothes on.

Is there a trick to do this with console commands, or other in-game techniques?  Or will I have to go install a mod of some kind?

Comment: Related: [How can you get your spouse to undress?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/70855/4797)

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod that lets you give your spouse clothes called "[Marriage Dynamic Outfits - Spouse Redress and Hugging features](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23099)".  I use it to redress Vilkas.